# Which Constraint solver is extensible to CSP algorithms?

Tags: solver, constraint-programming, java

I am novice to constraint programming and I need to implement the following algorithms.

1. Backtacking
2. Conflict-based backjumping
3. AC partial lookahead
4. MAC
5. Forward checking
6. Forward checking + dom
7. Forward checking + LCV'

Is it easy to extensible with available constraint solvers?

Or should I implement from start to end?
Is there any solver that includes those algorithms?

Comment: have a look a this maybe, it doesn't support confict based backjumping,but I think it covers the rest, and you should be able to extend the heuristics easily https://bitbucket.org/yanargyr/csp